# What's the answer to this differential equation of a ball rolling in a semi-circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, acceleration, differential-equations

Salute, everyone.

Let's assume a ball with a mass $m$ starts falling from the top of a frictionless semi-circular hole in the ground whose radius is $r$.

From Newtons second law, we have:

$$P_x = ma$$

$$g\cos\alpha = a$$

$\alpha$ being the angle the ball traversed.
Neat. Now from the law of conservation of energy, we have:

$$Ec_f = W(P)$$
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = mgh$$

And $h = r\,(1-\cos\alpha)$, therefore:

$$v = \sqrt{2gr\,(1-\cos\alpha)}$$

Now from the equation we got earlier about the acceleration we have:

$$\frac{1}{g} \frac{dv}{dt} = \cos\alpha$$

Therefore:

$$v = \sqrt{2gr \left(1-\frac{1}{g} \frac{dv}{dt}\right)}$$

$$v^2 = 2gr \left(1 - \frac{1}{g} \frac{dv}{dt}\right)$$
$$v^2 = 2gr - 2r \frac{dv}{dt}$$

In the end we get:

$$\frac{dv}{dt} + \frac{1}{2r}v^2 = g$$

So I am wondering, is there a solution to this differential equation that'd describe us speed at any given time?

Comment: @Frobenius I'd like to know, why did you add the homework tag? It's not a homework

Comment: With initial condition $v(0)=0$ solution is given by $v(t)=\sqrt{2 g r} \tanh \sqrt{\frac{g t^2}{2r}} $

Comment: @AlexTrounev Hi. Thanks for your response. Can you tell me how you got this so that I can check whether it's true or not.

Comment: It does not matter, since equation you drive is not right. The right equation is $\dot{v}^2+\frac {v^4}{4 r^2}=g^2$

Comment: @AlexTrounev May I know where the mistake is please?  And that equation of yours seems illogical a bit, and I'd need proof thereof.

Comment: My equation describes periodic movement as it should in a case of frictionless semi-circular hole , while your equation describes monotonic velocity increasing from 0 up to $\sqrt{2g r}$ at $t\rightarrow \infty$ .   The  proof is as follows. First, $\dot {v} =-g \cos \alpha$, second, $mv^2/2=mg(r-z)$ , where `z` counted from bottom, third, $\sin\alpha=(r-z)/r$. Finally, use $\sin^2 \alpha+\cos ^2\alpha=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation can be written as
$$2r\int \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{2rg-v^2}=\int \mathrm{d}t$$
Now we can use the standard integral
$$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{a^2-x^2}=\frac{1}{2a}\ln\left(\frac{a+x}{a-x}\right)+C$$ to finally get
$$\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{2rg}+v}{\sqrt{2rg}-v}\right)=(t+C)\sqrt{\frac{2g}{r}}$$
Knowing the initial conditions, we can calculate $C$.

Comment: Hello sir
 Thank you for your response. May I know how that integration technique is called?

Comment: Separation of variables